# Python TCPclient won't acknowledge

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am writing a TCP client in python that needs to get a math problems from a server when it connects to it and answer them.
I connected to the server with Netcat and saw this on Wireshark:
[image]

When I did it with my code I saw this 
[image]

The only difference is that after the server sends the question my code doesn't ACK to it.

Here is my code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'x.x.x.x'
port = 1337
s.connect((host, port))

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    splited_data = data.splitlines()
    exercise = splited_data[-1].decode("utf-8")
    print(exercise) 
    exercise = splited_data[-1].split()
    num1 = int(exercise[0])
    arithmetic = exercise[1].decode("utf-8")
    num2 = int(exercise[2])

    if arithmetic == '+':
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif arithmetic == '-':
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif arithmetic == '*':
        answer = num1 * num2
    elif arithmetic == '/':
        answer = num1 / num2
    elif arithmetic == '%':
        answer = num1 % num2
    else:
        print(arithmetic)

    print(answer)
    print(str(answer).encode('utf-8'))
    s.send(str(answer).encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever protocol the server uses to encapsulate these problems into messages, your code has no corresponding code to receive such messages. You'll need to follow the documentation for the protocol the server is using or, if the protocol is undocumented, reverse engineer it.

TCP is a byte stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries. To implement messages, you need to write a message layer. You have written no such code.

Whenever two programs are going to exchange messages, they have to have some agreement on how the beginning and end of those messages are marked and identified. The sender must have code to mark the end of the messages as agreed. The receiver must have code to find the end of the messages. Your receiver has no such code, so it cannot reliably figure out where the messages end.

Comment: but how is that with netcat I can send and receive messages and with my python client I cant? AFAIK ACK is sent automatically when you do socket.recv

Comment: @YonatanKreiner Without knowing the protocol the server is using, I can't explain precisely how it fails. But it will definitely fail since it implements no protocol at all. (Can you add the details of the protocol the server is using to your question so I can improve my answer?)

Comment: I dont have it, Its a CTF I just need to send and receive data over TCP like I do with Netcat

Comment: That makes no sense. With netcat, you are manually identifying the end of the messages with your human eye. You want to write a program to do that. So you will need to reverse engineer how the ends of the messages are marked. To write a program to do something a human does, you need to figure out *how* the human is doing it so you can replicate that.

Comment: For example, say you see "2+3". How do you know that's a complete message and not part of "2+32" and you just haven't received the last "2" yet? However you do that with netcat, you need to write code to do it so your program can do it.

Comment: I dont quite understand you, in my code I do recv(1024) and get all the message, and my code succeeds to solve the math problem and send it back just fine

Comment: @YonatanKreiner What is not clear? Where is the code to determine whether or not you got the whole message? Where is the code to call `recv` again if you didn't? Yes, I agree, a human can, by human eye, determine if the message is complete. But *where is the code to do that automatically*? I agree that a human can find the end of the message by understanding the protocol, but a computer can only do that if there's code to implement the protocol. *Where is that code?*

Comment: Can I do that without knowing how the server works? I know that my message wont be grater than 1024 so I need to send ACK after every message I receive

Comment: @YonatanKreiner You'll have to reverse engineer the protocol if it's not documented. Maybe it's marked with a line feed or carriage return. Maybe there's a zero byte. How are you telling when you use `netcat`? Are you just assuming you have the whole message?

Answer (score 0):

I would use s.close() behind your while loop to end your connection.

In your first Wireshark snippet it looks like that one side is not able to shutdown a TCP connection properly.

Comment: Yeah I know but this is not the problem I encounters. I will close the socket after I fix this issue